# Need some pointers

Tags: iphone, c

I'm trying to figure out a program in c to calculate the x,y coordinates in a bolt circle pattern. I've got the math part right but can't figure out how to get it to list the starting angle and coordinates first instead of last and the degrees not to go past 360. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float x;        //x location
    float y;        //y location
    float h;        //# of holes
    float d;        //diameter of bc
    float a;        //starting angle
    int n;          //hole count

    printf("enter dia of circle\n");
    scanf("%f", &d);
    printf("enter number of holes\n");
    scanf("%f", &h);
    printf("enter starting angle, counter clockwise from 3:00\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    float r = d / 2;    //radius
    float k = 360 / h;  //degrees between holes 

    for (n = 0; n < h; n++) {
        a = a + k;

        x = r * (cos(a * M_PI / 180));
        y = r * (sin(a * M_PI / 180));

        printf("%.3f, %.3f, %.2f\n", x, y, a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm doing this in c to get the code right then I'll put it in objective c for the iPhone, what would be the best way to list the output for each x & y coordinate and the angle? For example would I use a table view? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Just a suggestion - try naming your variables things that make sense. For example, [float h;        //# of holes] could also be written as [float numberOfHoles;] which then negates the comment, and makes other areas of your code more readable: [for (int holeCount = 0; holeCount < numberOfHoles; holeCount++)] - this is a good habit to get in to early on.

Comment: @Doug: mostly agreed, but those names are _huge_. `for (int h = 0; h < holes ; h++)` makes more sense to me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing `a = a + k` with something more like this:

```
float base_a;
printf("enter starting angle, counter clockwise from 3:00\n");
scanf("%f", &base_a);

for (n = 0; n < h; n++) {
    a = base_a + n*k;
```

Repeated addition of floating point numbers leads to increased errors. Maybe it won't matter for this (after all, you're only using `float`s rather than `double`s -- but errors accumulate "faster" with `float`s than `double`s, so it is a more pressing problem) but the fix is easy enough: multiply the difference with the count and add that to a constant base.

I'm also a little worried about the comparison `n < h` -- `n` is an `int` while `h` is a `float`. While I'm normally worried about floating-point loop variables, I'm *more* worried about a float being used for the number of holes. Is that what the problem specifies?

Comment: I changed the h to int, didn't need to be a float. That got me where I needed to be thanks for the help. Got any advice for me on the second part of the question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough iOS to help you with that portion of your question -- I suggest un-selecting my answer in the hopes that someone else can give you a better answer.

Comment: That's ok, I'll figure it out. All part of the learning process. Thanks again.